# How do you handle an empty Rest call when trying to copy data in azure data factory?

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I have a copy data activity in which my source dataset is set to a RestResource. It works fine except for every once in a while the Rest call returns an empty dataset: `{"d":{"results":[]}}`

This results in the following error

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorTypeInSchemaTableNotSupported,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to get the type from schema table. This could be caused by missing Sql Server System CLR Types.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Type'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Import Punch Adjustments",
    "details": []
}
```

I know for other sources you would want to do a lookup or check the metadata then do a conditional if, but I am unsure how to do that for a rest source. Are there any other better options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an activity on failure, this way even the copy activity fails pipeline will run successfully.

Example:

I have added an activity to store the error code on failure.

```
@string(activity('Copy data1').Error.errorCode)
```

[image]

[image]

**Pipeline status:**

[image]

Comment: This took care of what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help.